# O365 to splunk app via a proxy (o365tosplunkapp)

Tags: office365, splunk

I am trying to get splunk to pull logs from an o365 tenant.  I have the o365tosplunkapp installed but it doesnt seem to want to connect.

I get an error:   "Encountered the following error while trying to save: In Handler 'o365tosplunkdataimport:' One or more errors occurred"

I have to connect to the internet via a proxy and the app doesnt have ant options to add proxy urls or authentication so I am guessing this may be a problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You may have better luck opening an issue on the project's GitHub repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/o365tosplunkdataimportapp

Comment: Thanks, I will try there. They have a link to stack exchange :-)